# How to make a phone call directly from the app using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, call

I tried `react-native-phone-call` and also tried with `Linking` in react native but these two methods, first open dialer screen with number provided and then we have to manually press on call icon on dialer screen.

I want call should directly initiate from my project app. It should not open dialer app and then call.

I want to build something like this but in react native : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDwj5j4tBYg&t=19s

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linking to open the phone number in dialled content.

Working example: https://snack.expo.dev/@msbot01/spunky-yellow-waffle

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Button, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      
      <Button
        onPress={() => {Linking.openURL('tel:987323131');}}
        title="Call Helpline"
      />
      
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution opens number dialed on dialer screen, I want direct call from project application, it should not open dialer screen, it should open phone call screen with hand up button

Comment: Use this Library
https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent